# Protocol indirectly implementing another protocol more than once

Tags: swift

I'm doing some test projects to learn Swift, and there's a compilation issue that I am unable to solve.

I've defined a protocol like this:

```
@objc protocol MyDataProvider : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, NSObjectProtocol {
    var myData : AnyObject { get }
}
```

and a class implementing it:

```
class MyData : NSObject, MyDataProvider {
    var myData:AnyObject

    init() {
        self.myData = Int()
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I can create an instance of that class and reference it via a protocol variable:

```
let dataProvider : MyDataProvider = MyData()
```

Next, I want to use that instance in a view controller:

```
class MyController : UIViewController {
    let dataProvider : MyDataProvider = MyData()

    @IBOutlet var collectionView : UICollectionView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView.dataSource = dataProvider
        self.collectionView.delegate = dataProvider
    }
}
```

The last 2 assignments are reported as errors by the compiler, with the following error message:

```
Type 'MyDataProvider' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'
```

If I do not use the interface and declare the property as class type:

```
let dataProvider = MyDate()
```

it does compile. So there must be something wrong in the `MyDataProvider` protocol, I just can't figure out what.

If I remove one of the 2 delegates the interface implements, after commenting the corresponding line in `viewDidLoad()` compilation still fails. But if I remove the `NSObjectProtocol` from the protocol:

```
protocol MyDataProvider : UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var myData : AnyObject { get }
}
```

compilation now succeeds. Ok, `UICollectionViewDelegate` implements `NSObjectProtocol`, so it looks like a protocol cannot implement another protocol more than once, either directly or indirectly. But if I remove `NSObjectProtocol` from the interface and leave the two collection view delegates:

```
protocol MyDataProvider : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var myData : AnyObject { get }
}
```

compilation still fails, because both implement `NSObjectProtocol`. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has been fixed in beta 3. So I guess it was a bug. I was about to file a radar, but in the end they've been *swifter* than me :)